# How can I install a .deb file from command line?

Tags: installation, command-line

I am running 13.04 and in terminal I am trying to install *guitar pro 6 for linux* as it will not install with Ubuntu software center. I am in the correct directory and if I `ls` the directory, I get `GP6.deb` which is the folder I downloaded `guitarpro6` to, but when I use `apt-get install GP6.deb` Terminal accepts the command but says it cannot locate the file.

Am I using the correct command or must I do something else first?

Answer (score 10):

`.deb` files are installed using the `dpkg` command. So use the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i GP6.deb
```

- `-i` tells `dpkg` to **i**nstall

If it gives you errors about other packages/dependencies, run the following to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

- `-f` tells `apt-get` to **f**ix missing dependencies

Comment: Hi I have done this and it now shows this: deprima@deprima-K53U:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
deprima@deprima-K53U:~/Downloads$ apt-get install GP6.deb
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root? so Im unsure what to do now?

Comment: @user172503 No, you didn't do as in the answer. Read carefully. You made several mistakes: mixed up `dpkg` and `apt-get`, you omitted `sudo` and the order is wrong.

Comment: @user172503, forget about `apt-get install GP6.deb`, that is not the correct command. Just enter in both the commands in my answer (exactly as they are) in the order shown, and you should be on your way.